# Leaf Area Index (LAI) processing software

Tags: software-recommendations, free-software

I took a bunch of hemispherical vegetation images with a fisheye lense in the field. Now I am looking for a software that can (semi-)automatically translate these images in LAI values. So far I struggled with CanEye but didn't get results.
Anybody knows a good freeware solution?

Comment: My reading of your Question does not lead me to think that it is specifically about GIS.  W\If you disagree, would you be able to edit your Question to explain how that is the case, please?

Comment: Oh well, yes, you are right. It is an indicator of vegetation growth and structure which is used in remote sensing. I consult this forum so intuitively that I somehow thought it might be the right place. No help so far, so maybe I was wrong. But maybe I am lucky and somebody else working in remote sensing finds his way here...

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for the same and found CAN-EYE by INRA. Not only are they really the scientific leaders on this research, but they have made it available for free to everyone.
CAN-EYE is an imaging software (Windows) used to extract the following canopy structure characteristics from true-color images (either acquired with a fish-eye or with a classic objective)

LAI : Leaf Area Index
ALA : Average Leaf inclination Angle
FAPAR : Fraction of Absorbed Photosynthetically Active Radiation
FCOVER : Vegetation cover fraction
Bidirectional gap fraction

https://www6.paca.inra.fr/can-eye/

CAN-EYE is a free software developed since 2003 at EMMAH (Environnement Mediterranéen et Modélisation des Agro-Hydrosystèmes) by INRA (french National Institute of Agronomical research).